# Best Continuous Delivery Open Source tool with good community base

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

We need a Continuous Delivery tool which is free to  use. Hence, which is the best option out there?

Also, the community base for this tool should be widespread to support.

Comment: This is off-topic on SO. You *might* be interested in supporting a couple of sister site proposals where, if the proposals succeed, questions like this *might* be on-topic: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops?referrer=cZS_mCq3NdL7h376hrOevQ2 and http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93761/software-comparisons?referrer=cZS_mCq3NdIRDdBKtnO1dQ2 (you'd have to join Area51 SE for that, tho)

Comment: And, of course, http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, if you re-phrase the question (which the best -> looking for a tool with blah requirements)